# sed comment several lines

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a text file `test.txt` with something like the following:

```
foo
configure
top
start
fun
bar
hello
```

I want to comment out line numbers 2, 5 and 7, so that the output would look like:

```
foo
#configure
top
start
#fun
bar
#hello
```

When I use `sed -i "2,7 {s/^/#/}" test.txt` lines 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 get commented. How to ensure only specific line numbers are commented?
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `2,7` you specify a *range* of lines to apply the expression on. In this case, you just want to pick three specific lines.

```
sed -e '2s/^/#/' -e '5s/^/#/' -e '7s/^/#/'  file
```

or with the actual commenting-out operation separated out into a single place in he `sed` editing code (only really useful if you need to do something that would be more complicated than just adding a `#` to the start of the line):

```
sed -e 2bc -e 5bc -e 7bc -e b -e :c -e 's/^/#/' file
```

The `b` command branches to a label (here `c`, defined with `:c`) or to the end of the script if no label is given.

or with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == 2 || NR == 5 || NR == 7 { print "#" $0; next } 1'  file
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The sed works when I change `'` to `"`. But the awk fails with `awk: 'NR
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
'NR' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'NR' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`. Can you please suggest why?

Comment: @ArijitBanerjee Yes, that is not surprising. Why would you want to change the quotes?

Comment: Changed because I was getting `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `'' `

Comment: @ArijitBanerjee What Unix shell are you trying to run this in?

Comment: I am using `Gow (Gnu On Windows)` and from its documentation I can see it supports bash & zsh

Comment: @ArijitBanerjee Well, whatever you are using, its quoting is seriously broken.  The `awk` script _needs_ to be single-quoted because it contains a double-quoted string. Changing the single quotes to double quotes would break it on _any_ Unix platform. I would suggest switching to a platform that is "more Unix", such as Cygwin or Microsoft's own Ubuntu `bash` shell.

Comment: okay I will try them as you suggest. Thank you :)