# how to comment out many lines in a file with sed

Tags: shell-script, sed

in a file I have the following lines

```
foo
bar
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

I need to comment out the lines xxx, yyy, zzz. So I run the [following command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17999003/8747573):

```
sed -e '/xxx/ s/^#*/#/' -i file
sed -e '/yyy/ s/^#*/#/' -i file
sed -e '/zzz/ s/^#*/#/' -i file
```

out

```
foo
bar
#xxx
#yyy
#zzz
```

How can I do this in a loop (to check if all the lines that interest me, are or are not commented, and if they are not, comment them)?

thanks

PD: [This command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439809/266428) can be useful, if I knew the line number, but I don't know because it can vary.

```
sed -e '2s/^/#/' -e '5s/^/#/' -e '7s/^/#/'  file
```

PD: I can't use EOF either, because each line is a regex

Comment: See if `seq 5 | sed -E '/^(1|3|5)$/s,^,#,'` helps you any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this example text:

```
foo
bar
xxx
yyy
zzz
foo
bar
#xxx
#yyy
#zzz
```

You can use this command:

```bsh
$ sed 's/^\(xxx\|yyy\|zzz\)$/#\1/' file
foo
bar
#xxx
#yyy
#zzz
foo
bar
#xxx
#yyy
#zzz
```

---

- `^[^#]*` parse the lines that don't start with a `#`.
- `\(xxx\|yyy\|zzz\)` search for either `xxx`, `yyy` or `zzz`, capture them, and substitute for `#` and the captured pattern `#\1`.

Comment: great. you only needed add "-i" to modify the file. thanks

Answer (score 2):

With the following example data in `file`:

```
foo
bar
xxx
yyy
zzz
foo
bar
#xxx
#yyy
#zzz
```

Using a `sed` that has `-E` for using extended regular expressions:

```bsh
$ sed -E 's/^(xxx|yyy|zzz)$/#&/' file
foo
bar
#xxx
#yyy
#zzz
foo
bar
#xxx
#yyy
#zzz
```

With `awk`:

```bsh
$ awk '/^(xxx|yyy|zzz)$/ { $0 = "#" $0 }; 1' file
foo
bar
#xxx
#yyy
#zzz
foo
bar
#xxx
#yyy
#zzz
```

Using standard `sed`:

```bsh
$ sed -e '/^xxx$/bc' -e '/^yyy$/bc' -e '/^zzz$/bc' -e b -e ':c' -e 's/./#&/' file
foo
bar
#xxx
#yyy
#zzz
foo
bar
#xxx
#yyy
#zzz
```

Comment: thank you for your effort. They work, but they cannot be used in any scenario.

Comment: @ajcg Then you may want to update your question with scenarios that are not yet covered.